# css issue with tables

Tags: css

I asked a question a few minutes ago and tried all of the suggestions. I still am having an issue getting this just right. I have found the block of css that is causing the issues and need a solution.

I have 2 files. The first file has all of the css that I used when I made the form. When I had the form looking the way I liked it, I put all of that relevant code into a different stylesheet. The new stylesheet is overriding some of my values and causing things to look bad.

This is what I want and is all I require.

```
#password #header td {
padding-top:90px;
vertical-align:top;
}
```

---

This however is the block of code that is making things break. I don't want any of this. Is there a way to override it? The line-height specifically is really making things look horrible. If I remove the line height attribute then other parts of my site break.

```
td, th {
color:#000000;
font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
line-height:17px;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override all the attributes in your general css declarations into your specific style and add !important to ensure it is followed, e.g. for line height you can use:

```
#password #header td {
  padding-top:90px;
  vertical-align:top;
  line-height: normal !important;
}
```

Comment: Now this may be a winner, Manny. brb.

Comment: The use of !important is not best practice, see http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/

Comment: @AU Steve, It may not be the best practice but Manny's solution was the one that worked. What would you recommend?

Comment: Hi Tom, use !important sparingly.  If it works without it, remove it from the code.  I just wanted to introduce that there is such a thing as !important and you can use it if it's necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing line-height to something a little smaller. Something like this (targeting specific problem elements):

```
#password #header td {
  line-height:10px;
}
```

You can also specify `normal` to `line-height`:

```
#password #header td {
  line-height:normal;
}
```

Comment: Hey Alex, thanks again for helping me out. I've tried that but it takes all of my text and puts it almost on top of the other lines.

Comment: @Tom no problem. See my updated answer. CSS requires lots of tweaking and seeing what you like. From here just tweak your `line-height` until you like what you see.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? Just trying to help out here. But ok.

Comment: Alex, it wasn't me.. I was going to ask as well. I'm sorry that you got down voted.

Comment: @Tom I know it wasn't you. I was asking the community in general. Thanks though. :) I'm glad that you were finally able to solve your problem.

Comment: Ooh, I had forgotten about the `normal` value.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly override it in the specific style, like this:

```
#password #header td {
    padding-top:90px;
    vertical-align:top;
    line-height:12px; /*Or whatever is relevant*/
}
```

Check out Firebug's CSS browser and calculator to see what is the "default" value.

Comment: I've tried to adjust the line height to whatever the browser interprets if the line-height attribute is absent but I can't get it right. It just doesn't look the same.